# SNOWFLAKE Issue with XML Text() nodes getting 'Trimmed'

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following SQL

```
select PARSE_XML('<X>ABCDE </X>')
```

Generates

```
Row
<X>ABCDE</X>
```

Note that the trailing space on the text() node has been truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this is a bug, since whitespace in a general text node is significant.

If you report it, perhaps the current preview version will be corrected before general availability.